# magento 2.3.5. is it still safe

Tags: magento2

Is it still possible to use magento 2 Ver. 2.3.5 without any problems, are there security patches for this?
it is not security patch for 2.3.5. So now I'm unprotected?

Answer (score 0):

It is unprotected. Magento recommended to update PHP and Magento version as soon as possible. See below:
[image]

> **Support for the 2.3 release line ended on September  8, 2022.**
> https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/versions.html?lang=en